# Are there preset heroes in Might and Magic: Heroes 6?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I just got Might and Magic: Heroes 6 today and tried to play a quick hot-seat game with a friend to get the hang of it. The problem is, when selecting our heroes, only one was available for two players. We had to go through the dynasty screen to create one hero each.

Is there another way to get heroes, like the preset AI ones? Or, at least, to create a one-use hero?

Comment: I've tried creating some hot-seat games and I haven't gotten any option to select a dynasty hero.  Could you specify what options you chose to start the game?

Comment: @bwarner Nothing special, I just used the default parameters. Have you tried clicking the arrow over your hero's portrait?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are preset heroes, but only if you play Heroes VI offline.  When you aren't connected to the Conflux, you can choose from a list that contains a single Might and a single Magic hero from each faction.

[image: List of Generic Heroes]

When you are connected to the Conflux, you are restricted to your dynasty heroes and the factions they represent.  However, as you finish the campaigns, you gain the heroes from those campaigns.  I'm guessing (hoping?) that once you have finished all the campaigns you will have a might and a magic hero from every faction in your dynasty.

If I'm wrong, or if you want to play online skirmish or multi-player games right now (and be able to choose the faction you start with), you have to create your own hero for each faction.

Comment: You can customize your campaign hero as well, so as long as you take them through the campaign, you can pretty much shoot for whoever you want first (post tutorial campaign).